# Scrolling issue with WebView inside UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, scroll, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` in which each of the child view controller contains a `WKWebview`. 
The content of WebView is structured in two parts:

- The top part contains a fixed size header in a `div`.
- The bottom part contains the content, that can be larger than the device.

You can see a representation in the following drawing:

[image: Description]

When the content is larger than the device, the user needs to scroll the content horizontally until the end of it in order for the `UIPageViewController` to start the swipe between two pages, and this is expected.

The problem is that the top part contains a fixed size header, and so if the user starts the scrolling in the header, it still need to scroll horizontally to the end of the content for the swipe to start. This is obviously not user friendly, and I am not sure how to solve this issue.

Do you have any suggestions about this?

Comment: it's a real problem in fact. Why don't you disable swiping UIPageViewControl?

Comment: @maku Because the swiping is exactly the reason UIPageViewController was used in the first place.

Comment: If top content has fixed height, then you should handle start of scrolling, check if pan location inside your header, if so – 1. disable web view scrolling. 2. scroll to the next page in code. 3. enable web view scrolling.

Comment: @StasVolskiy, in general it makes sense, but how would you deal with the panning given that there is a PageViewController involved? Also you can't simply disable the scrolling, otherwise you can't scroll down, because the content could go further down.

Comment: @markusian well, you can't do it in a simple way. Regarding vertical scroll – you can also detect scroll direction. If you see that user doing horizontal scroll in header – scroll page view controller instead, otherwise do nothing. if you will handle it correctly it will work. However you will loose PageViewController pan gesture, because you will do it in the code (when in header)

Comment: @markusian actually scrolling can get problem when you using gestures. Your pagination must be left to right and right to left -----scrolling must be top to bottom and bottom to top. Because scrolling and gestures not in same direction. Once you check it your scrolling and paging are same direction or not. If same scrolling won't enable.

Comment: Do you know the size and location of the header?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it something like:

1. Take two different UIPaginationViews, One for Header and one for
   Contents.
2. Now, add these UIPaginationView's to ScrollView and enable vertical scrolling.
3. In delegate method, if the user scroll the page of Header
   PaginationView then you can set the appropriate Index on the
   Contents PaginationView. As the width of the Header is equal to the
   width of the screen, so scrolling it to next page is smooth.
4. Now, when user scrolls on the bottom content and page get's
   changed then you will have to set the index on the top pagination
   view to match the contents pagination view.
5. In the scrollView, Allow only vertical scrolling. so, when you
   scrolls it will scroll both the UIPaginations views.

it will need little experiments to get the desired behaviour and first thing you will have to do is to separate the HEADER AND CONTENT. if that is possible then you can try this approach.

Hope it helps.